# Testear actions que llaman a servicios

Tags: reactjs

Tengo que hacerle test a unas actions que llaman a los servicios que conectan con el back pero no consigo hacerlo, añado los ficheros a continuacion:

configuration.actions

```
import configurationService from '../services/configuration.service';

function getAllCountries() {
  return configurationService.getAllCountries();
}
```

configuration.service.js

```
import BACKEND_ROUTES from '../constants/backendroutes';
import history from '../helpers/history';
import ROUTES from '../constants/routes';
import responses from './responses';

const getToken = () => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  if (user.status === 200) {
    const token = user.result;
    return token;
  }
  history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
  return true;
};

function getAllCountries() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    // headers: authHeader()
  };

  const url = `${BACKEND_ROUTES.CONFIGURATIONDS_GET_ALL_COUNTRIES}?token=${getToken()}`;
  return fetch(`${url}`, requestOptions).then(responses.handleResponseConfig);
}

export default configurationService;
```

configuration.actions.test.js

```
import configurationService from '../../services/configuration.service';
import '../../services/__mocks__/configuration.service';

describe('Configuration Actions', () => {
  it('prueba fetch', () => {
    configurationService.getAllCountries().then(description => {
      expect(description).toBe('OK');
    });
  });
});
```

El error que me devuelve al ejecutarlo es el siguiente:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea está accesando a *localStorage*. 
`const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`

Si aún no lo tienes debes crear un mock de tu localStorage. Podrías usar [jest-localstorage-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock).

Después en el setup de tus pruebas tendrías que agregar las siguientes líneas:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  return localStorage.setItem('user', 'testToken');
});
```

También te recomiendo probar para el caso donde no tienes *userToken* para manejar el error correctamente y no el que arroja de `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null`